# Getting Errors When Running Appium Script In Python

Tags: selenium, appium

So I'm running into this error when I try and run my script.  Appium is running and tried with both the simulator running on and off.  Is there something missing I'm not seeing?

Script:

```
import unittest
import os
from appium import webdriver
from time import sleep

class SimpleIOSTests(unittest.Testcase):

     def setup(self):

     app = os.path.abspath('/Users/gleviern/appium/UICatalog.app')
     self.driver = webdriver.Remote(
         command_executor='127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub',
         desired_capabilities={
               'app': app,
               'platformName': 'iOS',
               'platformVersion': '10.1',
               'deviceName': 'iPhone 7',
               'automationName': 'XCUITest'
      })

     def tearDown(self):
          self.driver.quit()

     def test_first_element_click(self):

          driver = self.driver

          element = driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id('Picker View')
          element.click()

if __name__ == '__main__':
      suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(SimpleIOSTests)
      unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "appiumTest.py", line 6, in <module>
class SimpleIOSTests(unittest.Testcase):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Testcase'
```

Comment: Nm.  found the bugger

Comment: Did you have a script named `unittest.py`?

Comment: no.  in my class it was Testcase and not TestCase.  Typo on my part.  Now running into another error:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
            File "appiumTest.py", line 23, in tearDown
              self.driver.quit()
     AttributeError: 'SimpleIOSTests' object has no attribute 'driver'

Comment: Gotcha, another typo: `setUp` vs `setup`.

Comment: And that fixed the rest of the errors.....Thanks!

Comment: Glen, please add an answer to this question indicating what the problems were and why they were a problem. This will help testers who are not all that familiar with coding to understand that many languages are case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that capitalization is significant.

"Testcase" should be "testCase"

"setup" should be "setUP"